# Error: incorrect data length (argument="gaslane", value={"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x2386f26fc10000"}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.6.4)

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

Here is an image:

[image]

this is **01-deploy-raffle.js**

```
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../helper.hardhat-config")
const { verify } = require("../helper.hardhat-config")

const VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseEther("30")

module.exports = async function ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) {
const { deploy, log } = deployments
const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
const chainId = network.config.chainId
let vrfCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId

if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
    const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
    vrfCoordinatorV2Address = vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.address
    const transactionResponse = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()
    const transactionReciept = await transactionResponse.wait(1)
    subscriptionId = transactionReciept.events[0].args.subId

    await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT)
} else {
    vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"]
    subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"]
}

const callbackGasLimit = networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"]
const entranceFee = networkConfig[chainId]["entranceFee"]
const interval = networkConfig[chainId]["interval"]
const gasLane = networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"]

const args = [
    vrfCoordinatorV2Address,
    interval,
    entranceFee,
    gasLane,
    subscriptionId,
    callbackGasLimit,
]
const raffle = await deploy("Raffle", {
    from: deployer,
    args: args,
    log: true,
    waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
})

if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
    log("Verifying...")
    await verify(raffle.address, args)
}

log("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "raffle"]
```

this is **helper.hardhat-config**

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat")

const networkConfig = {
4: {
    name: "rinkeby",
    subscriptionId: "6926",
    vrfCoordinatorV2: "0x6168499c0cFfCaCD319c818142124B7A15E857ab",
    entranceFee: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.01"),
    gasLane: "0xd89b2bf150e3b9e13446986e571fb9cab24b13cea0a43ea20a6049a85cc807cc",
    subscriptionId: "0",
    callBackGasLimit: "500000",
    interval: "30",
},
31337: {
    name: "hardhat",
    entranceFee: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.01"),
    gasLane: "0xd89b2bf150e3b9e13446986e571fb9cab24b13cea0a43ea20a6049a85cc807cc",
    callbackGasLimit: "500000",
    interval: "30",
},
}

const developmentChains = ["hardhat", "localhost"]
module.exports = {
networkConfig,
developmentChains,
}
```

I got this error when I ran "yarn hardhat deploy". Those are the codes that I think are creating the problem. Any type of help would be appreciated, thank you

000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 2):

make sure that the `args` order in the deploy.js is as same as the contract's constructor's order.

I was facing the same issue, check this for more clarification: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-js/discussions/1300#discussioncomment-3222350

Comment: Thanks! saved me a whole lot of stress